# Calling php file via AJAX, using setInterval timer -- initial load time too long

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following function to call a php file every 10 seconds:

```js
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});    

$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("http://192.168.3.30/statustablephp.php", function(systemsupdown) {
                $('#systemsud').html(systemsupdown);
            });
        }, 10000);
    });
```

The php file is a table that pings ~10 IPs from the server and reports back reachable status as well as average response time. 
 The function works properly once it loads, but the initial load takes between 1-2 minutes (sometimes longer!) during which the window is blank. The table successfully updates every 10 seconds after this initial load so it does not appear to be an issue with the response time from the file. Is there a way to reduce that intial load time? I cannot understand why it takes so long initially when the file doesn't have any issues loading in 10 seconds later on.

EDIT: Adding the php that's being called:

```
<?php

$myServices = array
    (
    array(
        "name" => "abaqis", 
        "ip" => "www.abaqis.com", //[0]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "SNFs Admissions",
        "ip" => "www.helpmeenroll.com", //[1]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "INTERACT",
        "ip" => "interact2.net",//[2]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "IT Help Desk",
        "ip" => "help.provideris.com", //[3] 
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "ODH Gateway",
        "ip" => "interact2.net", //Not the real IP; picked one that pings fast so the function doesn't get hung up on this dead one; want to reserve the spot for later though so all the other numbers don't get messed up; taking the place of [4]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Omnicare Pharmacy",
        "ip" => "interact2.net", //Not the real IP; picked one that pings fast so the function doesn't get hung up on this dead one; want to reserve the spot for later though so all the other numbers don't get messed up; taking the place of [5]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "OptimaSolutions",
        "ip" => "www.foundationssolutions.com", //[6]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Outlook Webmail",
        "ip" => "mail.fhs-is.com", //[7]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "PointClickCare",
        "ip" => "www4.pointclickcare.com", //[8]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Procurement Partners",
        "ip" => "buyer.procurementpartners.com", //[9]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Quadax",
        "ip" => "interact2.net", //Not the real IP; picked one that pings fast so the function doesn't get hung up on this dead one; want to reserve the spot for later though so all the other numbers don't get messed up; taking the place of [10]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Remedi Pharmacy",
        "ip" => "www.remedirx.com", //[11]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Sex Offender Registry",
        "ip" => "www.icrimewatch.net", //[12]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "SigmaCare",
        "ip" => "login.sigmacare.com", //[13]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "UltiPro",
        "ip" => "interact2.net", //Not the real IP; picked one that pings fast so the function doesn't get hung up on this dead one; want to reserve the spot for later though so all the other numbers don't get messed up; taking the places of [14]
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "UR Patient Management",
        "ip" => "provider-ur.net", //[15]
    ),
);

function ping($target){

$result = array();

$cmd_result = shell_exec("ping -n 3 -w 500 ". $target);

$result = explode(",",$cmd_result);

if(eregi("Received = 0", $result[1])){
return false;
}
else{
    return true;
    }
};

$output = array();
$output2 = array();
$output3 = array();

function pinglat($tar) {
exec("ping -n 2 -w 500 $tar", $output, $status);
$output2 = explode(",",$output[8]);
$output3 = explode("=",$output2[2]);
return $output3[1];
};

$latencyResults = array();

foreach ($myServices as $value) {
    $pinglatResult = pinglat($value["ip"]);
    array_push($latencyResults, $pinglatResult);

};

$serverResults = array();
$ti = time();

foreach ($myServices as $value) {
       $pingResult = ping($value["ip"]);
       array_push($serverResults, $pingResult);                
};

    ?>
```

The only additional information in the php file is the html/css table itself. No images are loading. The entire php file is self-contained -- I am working with intranet software for a company and my only real option is to use widgets that only take a certain kind and certain amount of code. So I'm only using the widget for the JS/Ajax part, and I put everything else with the php file.

When it does load, it looks like this (and updates accordingly every 10 seconds):
[Status Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx2qZ.png)

Comment: are you 100% sure that the problem is not in the PHP file?

Comment: Not 100% sure. However, if there was a problem in the file, wouldn't it fail to update during the interval every 10 seconds? I have a timestamp and the "Response Time" averages do successfully update every 10 seconds. Since it's the same file being reloaded every time, wouldn't it have the same problem each time the setInterval forces it to run again if the problem was in the php file? Or are there potential php issues that can cause a problem the first time and not subsequent times?

Comment: If you have Chrome dev tools, check the network tab to see what request is taking so long to load the initial html page.  My guess is its a link to some remote library or asset that causes the page not to fully load.

Comment: please share the php ajax file as well, and do check if any external/intern file, image/js/css file is taking too much time to load...

Comment: Using Chrome dev tools, the entire delay is Waiting (TTFB). It's between 1-2 minutes. So, server-side. If the entire php file is being called every 10 seconds, though, how can it be delayed by 1-2 minutes one time and then successfully run every 10 seconds every time after that?

Comment: @EmilyTurner : Did you think about pinging them using parallel asyncronous tasks? if for some reasons a server takes longer than expected to respond to your request it may slow down everything else.